# JavaFX change scenes maintaining full screen

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen

I'm trying to change from one screen to another in full screen model but only the first screen is on full screen, when I change to another screen the full screen dosn't work.

Here's my code:

**Main**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**sample.fmxl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="First Screen" textAlignment="CENTER" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <StackPane layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="next" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#nextScreen" text="Next" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FirstScreenController**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button next;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    public void nextScreen(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        SecondScreenController secondScreen = new SecondScreenController();
        Stage stage = (Stage) next.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setFullScreen(true);

        secondScreen.start(stage);
    }

    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

**sample2.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.SecondScreenController">
    <children>
        <StackPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                    <children>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Second Screen" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
        <StackPane layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="back" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#backScreen" text="Back" />
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**SecondScreenController**

```
public class SecondScreenController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button back;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }


    public void backScreen(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        Controller firstScreen = new Controller();
        Stage stage = (Stage) back.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        firstScreen.start(stage);

    }
}
```

When I press the button Full Screen mode stop working, even if I go back to the first screen. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Instead of creating a new scene every time and calling `stage.setScene(...)`, can't you just replace the root of the scene?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: `scene.setRoot(....)`?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `window.setFullScreen(true);` in `SecondScreenController.java` before `window.show();`.

Also add `window.setFullScreen(true);` in `Controller.java` in `start()` before `window.show();`